# No inserta fecha

Tags: sql, date, insert

Estoy usando MySQL Workbench y tengo la siguiente tabla.

```
create table games
(
    idGame int primary key auto_increment not null,

    idTeamHome int(11) not null, 
    idTemaVisit int (11) not null,
    idFieldTeam int(11) not null,
    DateOfmatch date not null, -- fecha de partido
    statusGame bit default 0 not null -- 0 programado, 1 finalizado
);
```

Cuando hago un insert, me sale la señal de warning

> 1 row(s) affected, 1 warning(s): 1265 Data truncated for column
>   'DateOfmatch' at row 1    0.094 sec

Hace el insert, pero cuando hago un select a la tabla el campo de fecha sale asi 0000-00-00

El insert lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
INSERT INTO games(idTeamHome,idTemaVisit,idFieldTeam,DateOfmatch) VALUES (1,2,1,'2019-01-20');
```

Como puedo solucionar eso?

Comment: seguro que esa es la consulta que ejecutas y la tabla que usas? por que yo repliqué tu ejercicio y me inserta los valores sin problema

Comment: Segura, es la tabla correcta, cuando hago el insert me aparece ese warning, y al final salen ceros

Comment: igual pasate del entorno visual de `workbench` a la línea de comandos y replica la sentencia `INSERT` y coméntanos como te fue

Comment: elimine la base de datos, la volví a crear, y ya aparece.... a que se debe ese tipo de warning?

Comment: Ese warning es **imposible** sobre esta sentencia: `INSERT INTO games(idTeamHome,idTemaVisit,idFieldTeam,DateOfmatch) VALUES (1,2,1,'2019-01-20');` ya que la fecha es totalmente correcta. El hecho de que te creara la fecha como `0000-00-00` es un claro indicativo de que el warning ocurría sobre una consulta en la cual la fecha estaba equivocada. En MySQL el formato de la fecha es `YYYY-MM-DD`. Si intentas algo como esto: `INSERT INTO games(idTeamHome,idTemaVisit,idFieldTeam,DateOfmatch) VALUES (1,2,1,'2019-20-01');` tendrás el Warning, porque no existe un mes `20` y la fecha se creará indicas.

Comment: Para efectos de prueba podrías intentar realizar el insert con la función current_date() y compartirnos el resultado del INSERT. Quedaría algo parecido a esto: 
INSERT INTO test.games(idTeamHome,idTemaVisit,idFieldTeam,DateOfmatch) VALUES (1,2,1,current_date());